# How to increase elliptical arc resolution for high radius values in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I've been trying to draw an elliptical arc in openCV using the ellipse function (https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html), however, for high radius values the arcs seem segmented.

Do you know how can I sort of increase the arc's resolution to appear better for high radius values?

I tried to draw an arc with a small radius and it looked smooth and I also tried increasing image resolution but no difference was noticed.

My code is as follows:

```
A[0] = round(A[0]*dpm - Xmin + margin)         #Normalize CenterX
A[1] = round(A[1]*dpm - Ymin + margin)         #Normalize CenterY
A[2] = round(A[2]*dpm)                         #Normalize Radius
startAng = A[3] 
endAng = A[4]
A=A.astype(int)
cv2.ellipse(Blank,(A[0],A[1]),(A[2],A[2]), 0, startAng, endAng, 0 ,1)
```

while:
Blank is the image I want to draw the arc on (np array, size= (398, 847)

(A[0],A[1]) is the center point

(A[2],A[2]) ellipse axes

0 is the angle

startAng is the starting angle of the arc

endAng is the ending angle of the arc

0 is the line color (Black)

1 is the line thickess

The code should produce a smooth arc but it looks segmented as if it is made of 4 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a function to plot an arc on an input image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

blank = np.ones((500,500))

def DrawArc(image, center, radius, startAng, endAng, color,resolution):

    '''Draws an arc with specific reslution and color on an input image
    Args:
    image      - The input image to draw the arc on
    center     - Arc's center
    radius     - Arc's radius
    startAng   - the starting angle of the arc
    engAng     - the ending angle of the arc
    color      - Arc's color on the input image
    resolution - Number of points for calculation

    output:
    image      - updated image with plotted arc'''

    startAng += 90
    endAng += 90
    theta = np.linspace(startAng,endAng,resolution)
    x = np.round(radius*np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))) + center[0]
    y = np.round(radius*np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))) + center[1]
    x=x.astype(int)
    y=y.astype(int)

    for k in range(np.size(theta)):
        image[x[k]][y[k]] = color

    return image

image = DrawArc(blank,(250,250),200,0,90,0,1000)

cv2.imshow("Arc",image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The output image is
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdot7.png)